# Mapping a Flat Schema to a Repeating Schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

[Biztalk Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVO89.jpg)

Hi, I'm new to BizTalk. I literally have a single record in the source schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LogEntryResponse xmlns="...">
      <LogEntryResult>
        <TxId>string1</TxId>
        <ServiceName>string2</ServiceName>
        <Identifier>string3</Identifier>
        <Amount>string4</Amount>
        <Status>string5</Status>
        <Detail>string6</Detail>
      </LogEntryResult>
    </LogEntryResponse>
```

I would like use each of the elements to make an individual record in the target schema like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <ns1:processRequestResponse>
         <return>
            <name>string1</name>
            <value>string1</value>
         </return>
         <return>
            <name>string2</name>
            <value>string2</value>
         </return>
         <return>
            <name>string3</name>
            <value>string3</value>
         </return>
      </ns1:processRequestResponse>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

I have tried a number of things but it is clear I am doing something wrong. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be very simple.

All you have to do is link TxId, ServiceName, Identifier, etc. all to a Looping Functoid.  Then link from the Looping Functoid to Return.

Then you can link each individual field to Value and use a String Concatenate to set each of the Name fields.

Comment: I feel I owe you an apology :). Thank you and it gives me a better understanding of Mapping.

Comment: @Mabz You can populate the name field by clicking on the link going to name and changing the Source Links from "Copy text value" to "Copy name"